# How to test req.query using supertest node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, supertest

I have this code on `supertest` framework for tests:

```js
it('GET normal pending transfer with receiverId', (done) => {
      supertest(app)
        .get('/transfers/pending')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .expect(200)
        .query({
          senderId: clientSenderId,
        })
        .expect('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
        .then((res) => {
          console.log('res.body', res.body);
          done();
        })
        .catch(done);
    });
```

This endpoint - `/transfers/pending` takes query this way:

`const { receiverId, senderId } = req.query;`

As you can see, this is `req.query` and I want to send this query in my test's code.

I was trying to use this:

`.get('/transfers/pending?senderId=${clientSenderId}')`

And this:

```js
.query({
  senderId: clientSenderId,
})
```

And nothing of this isn't working. I mean, I got 500 and, the most important, I get an error in message, that **belongs to other endpoint**. It looks like my code triggers other endpoint, not that `/transfers/pending`.

My question is, how can I send queries in tests. With params and bodies everything works just fine, but not with queries.

Comment: It's a little weird to me,  why GET should accept JSON?

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. It works fine for me. Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @owenizedd it's a test, so, I think, this is just form of representation. It accepts queries.